# WCF with windows authentication problems

Tags: c#, wcf

I am building wcf aplication that will work only with users that have User+Password to the windows where this wcf is located.That mean is my wcf located on server X and i call function GetData(5) i will see the logon form (the same users that in windows) and entered User+Password and then get data back, my main goal is to pass User+Password to avoid this logon window,but now i can't  forse my wcf to ask for windows authentication,it is returning data to everyone.

What i am doing wrong?

I am using Vs2012(4.5)

> P.s if any one have example of wcf that use windows authentication i
>   will be very happy to see it.

My webConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService10.Service1">
        <endpoint address="WCF10" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding10"
          contract="WcfService10.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding10">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Type, Assembly" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />



  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure your service answers to everyone?  Default WCF client behavior is to retry the call with the current windows user passed as credentials when it receives a http 403:unauthorized error.

You can check the exact communication with a web debugging proxy like Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I checking this localy,but still i think i need to see popUp window to login,to avoid this window login it's my second goal.

Comment: You'll only get that login form when surfing to the service URL with  a browser, but with some constraints:
- if you use 'localhost' in your URL, WCF knows that the caller comes from the local machine, so no security will be checked.
- even if you use your PC name in the URL, Internet Explorer will automatically try to logon with your current windows user.  If that user is known on the target machine (you are testing locally, so that will always be the case), you'll see no login form.  Other browsers may have different behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass alternative windows credentials to a service, use the following code:

```
var proxy = new MyServiceClient();
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "MyDomain";
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "MyUsername";
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "MyPassword";
proxy.DoSomething();
proxy.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here one config with webHttpBinding and Windows Transport security. You have to change the service name, baseAddress, contract="Server.IServicemame"

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!--Services-->
    <services>
        <service name="Server.servicemame">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9011/servicemame/service"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Server.IServicemame" bindingConfiguration="HttpBindingWithSecurity">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <!--Behaviors-->
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="false" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--Bindings-->
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="HttpBindingWithSecurity">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>

        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: that gives me  error `Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.`